# Is it possible to auto split the .text section across mulitple memory areas?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, ld, elf

I am currently writting a embedded program for a microcontroller with a splitted flash region. Something like

```
MEMORY { 
    flash1  : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    /* 1K gap */
    flash2  : ORIGIN = 0x3000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
```

My application has grown to a point where the *".text"* section is larger than the area of *flash1*.
Is it possible to automatically split the text section accross the two areas?

Something like:

```
SECTIONS {
   .text0 : { *(.text) } > flash1
   .text1 : { *(.text) } > flash2  
}
```

If I am doing something like the one above. I get a error message telling me that

```
ld: a.out section `.text' will not fit in region `flash1'
ld: region `flash1' overflowed by 240 bytes
```

I know I could do something like:

```
SECTIONS {
   .text0 : { mylargefile (.text) } > flash1
   .text1 : { *(.text) }            > flash2  
}
```

but I don't have a single large file. So the question is is it possible to tell the linker to fill the first output section until the it is full and afterwards continue with the next section?

Further information:

I do not provide a full example as my actually application is much more complex as I am although using LMA and VMA section and special section for some special files. But this answer should provide me enough help to continue or ask further questions.

I am looking forward for answers. I hope my question is clear enough without a full sample

EDIT1:
The solution of the question [Splitting embedded program in multiple parts in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437877/splitting-embedded-program-in-multiple-parts-in-memory) is not correct in my case as the solution uses wildcards to spilt the files manually. I ask if there is a automatically solution. Otherwise I would be forced to manually adjust the linker file every time I do larger changes on the code base.

EDIT2:
Changed example to make sure there is a gap as remarked by [Tom V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13001961/tom-v)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437877/splitting-embedded-program-in-multiple-parts-in-memory

Comment: @KamilCuk The quest was answered by doing it manually via assigment of the files to the section. I ask if there is way that the linker does this behaviour on its own.

Comment: Related questions with no good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603028/gcc-linker-script-split-bss-section-to-multiple-ram-regions#comment119494837_67603028 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156201/gnu-linker-section-of-non-contiguous-memory-region

Comment: @Tagli thanks for the work. It looks like this is real not supported by ld which makes me a little sad as it shouldn't be that hard to support it. And looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156201/gnu-linker-section-of-non-contiguous-memory-region#comment110135202_15370242 tells me that I am not the only person think about this problem

Comment: Does your "something like" script not work?  I am not very familiar with GNU ld scripts, but ARM linker scatter-files can certainly do that (perhaps the clue is in the name).

Comment: The example memory layout you give does not have a gap (1000+1000=2000), please update the question.

Comment: @Clifford yes my something like script does not work. I was not aware that Arm linker scatter-files do support this. Sadly my toolchain requires gcc and ld as it is not a arm architecture. But I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Perhaps create a single ROM `ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x4000` with a dummy object from `0x2000 to 0x2FFF` that the linker would be forced to work around.  I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some compilers allow in their linkers (and the scripts) to overflow to another section, if the first one is full.

But also these have sometimes problems, that it depends on the order of when the section is full and when it switches, it does not come back to fill the first one up, e.g. you have in the beginning or the middle a very big part. When the linker skips now to the next section due to overflow, the first was maybe just filled to the half. It does not use smaller parts AFTER that big part, to go back to the first sections to fill in.

So, it seems, the GNU LD, the Gold-linker and also the LLVM/CLANG linker (which state at their site, that the linker script is the same as GNU LD, and the exceptions page does not state anything), do not support to overflow into another section.

So, to make it easier, maybe some hints:

- Filtering by filename patterns can get tedious over time. And, it does not allow you to filter by symbol, only by filename pattern and input section names.
- If you have a approach like AUTOSAR MemMap, you could split the code by placing them into new sections with a different naming than default `.text, .rodata, .data, .bss`. (Unfortunately, GCC + CLANG went that extra way of using **attribute**(( )) instead of the #pragma or _Pragma() way of the C-standard). (AUTOSAR MemMap example at the end)

  - you could split into fast and slow code, e.g. introducing new sections like `.codefast, .codeslow` (e.g. ISR code as fast, task level code as "slow")
  - you could split into QM vs ASIL partitions introducing sections like `.code_qm, .code_asila, .code_asilb`
  - you could split code and config / const data , where the configuration is put into a separately flashable section, e.g. sections `.text, .rodata` could be split into `.text, .const .postbuildconfig, .calib` .. with a partial different coding style, you could here keep the code the same, but project config (e.g. CAN config, filter chains etc) could use a configurable config, where you just flash a new config, without updating the code itself

    - `.text` --> flash memory sector 1
    - `.postbuildconfig` --> flash memory sector 2
    - `.calib` --> flash memory sector 3
- Before starting actually to really compile and link, maybe an inbetween build phase could use tools like `objdump / nm / size / readelf` to first scan over the `.o` files to give out the object / section sizes and summarize them by a script according to certain criterias e.g. input memory layout and by above special sections or by ordering by size and `.o` file name patterns, which you could use to update the linker script to adapt the memory definitions. SO, the script could try to fit until the gap as much as fits, then switches to the other memory. It could even try to generate the linker script parts which is later passed to the linker. You could write such a linker preprocess script in perl or python.

Together with the memory mapping to different sections, you could filter now like this:

```
MEMORY {
    // Maybe you have two 128k areas separate by a gap
    // Put the code in the first big part, and the more
    // "configurable part" in the second area might even 
    // allow you to flash/update the separately 
    CODE1     : origin = 0x10000, len = 128k
    // maybe here is a gap
    CODE2     : origin = 0x10000, len = 64k
    CONST     : origin = 0x20000, len = 4k
    CALIB     : origin = 0x40000, len = 4k
    POSTBUILD : origin = 0x50000, len = 48k
}
SECTIONS {
    .code1 : {
        *(.text)       // default .text
        *(.code_fast)  // fast/slow code split
        *(.code_qm)    // qm/asil code split
    } > CODE1
    .code2 : {
        *(.code_slow)  // fast/slow code split
        *(.code_asila) // qm/asil code split
        *(.code_asilb) // qm/asil code split
    } > CODE2
    .const : {
        *(.const)
        *(.rodata)
    } > CALIB
    
    .calib : {
        *(.calib)
        *_calib.o(.calib) // in case you separate them also out into xxx_Calib.c files compiled to xxx_Calib.o files
    } > CALIB
    
    .postbuild : {
         *(.postbuild)
         *_PBCfg.o(.postbuild) // in case you separate them also out into xxx_PBCfg.c files compiled to xxx_PBCfg.o files
     } > POSTBUILD
}
```

This approach allows you also to prepare the layout in a header, and generate that configs and calibs by certain external tools.

Additionally, it also allows a bit better to estimate your memory resource consumptions and therefore also, how and where to place/link them to the memory sections.

Here is an AUTOSAR MemMap usage example in code

```
#define XXX_START_SEC_CODE_FAST
#include "MemMap.h"

void XXX_Channel0_Notification(void) {
    // Channel0 Finished Notification e.g. called from ISR
}

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE_FAST
#include "MemMap.h"
```

The MemMap.h can configure this like:

```
#if defined(XXX_START_SEC_CODE_FAST)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CODE_FAST
// open section .codefast
#pragma section code ".codefast"

#elif defined(XXX_START_SEC_CODE_SLOW)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CODE_SLOW
// open section .codeslow
#pragma section code ".codeslow"
#endif

#if defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE_FAST)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE_FAST
// back to default section
#pragma section code 

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE_SLOW)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE_SLOW
// back to default section
#pragma section code 
#endif
```

The MemMap.h file could be generated, by scanning all the start/stop section defines, and generating the pragmas by a config tool (could be even Excel).

The advantage is, that you do not spill all the pragmas possible (e.g. different compilers <-> different dialects), or if to map or not to map. So you can actually reuse the code in different projects if possible.

Comment: I was hopping there is a solution build into LD but I guess after googling for a will and with all the comments and your answer. I guess the answer is sadly simple no. I am marking your answer as solve but could you add a short sum up that. LD does not support autosplitting and therefore the answer is to my question is no?

Answer (score 1):

An [`--enable-non-contiguous-regions` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002denable_002dnon_002dcontiguous_002dregions) was [added](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=abf874aafe3d717573e4a48bf0e3c6334e666a55) to ld in Binutils 2.35 (released in July 2020). As noted at the top of that manual page, you will typically need to prefix linker options with `-Wl,` (e.g. `gcc -Wl,--enable-non-contiguous-regions ...`). The example in your question will work as expected once this option is enabled. Unfortunately ld will not intelligently pack sections to minimize wasted space. When something doesn't fit, it just moves on to the next output section rather than trying to pack in subsequent, possibly smaller, input sections.

A couple other notes:

- Ignore the duplicate origin addresses in the example in the manual. It likely just a typo.
- The `--enable-non-contiguous-regions-warnings` option seems to be broken in a way that will produce thousands of useless warnings like:

  - "warning: --enable-non-contiguous-regions makes section '.bss' from './emptyfile.o' match /DISCARD/ clause." -- it's being discarded because it's empty, not because it matches a /DISCARD/ clause
  - "warning: --enable-non-contiguous-regions may change behaviour for section `.text.some_func' from './some_file.o' (assigned to .text, but additional match: .text2)" -- that's the whole point of the option

Comment: This is really good. I've noticed though that it gives up on a section as soon as it encounters one object too large to fit in it. This means it isn't exactly ideal when it comes to tightly packing a section.